# How To Permanently Add Source IP to Route Table Entry in CentOS 5.11

Tags: centos, networking, iproute

I have a multi-homed CentOS 5.11 server in which I have manually changed the default route entry so that packets are sourced from a particular IP (45.32.6.197).  How can I make this change permanent across reboots?

The command I used to change the default route is:

```
# ip route change default via 104.238.132.1 src 45.32.6.197
```

and the resulting routing table looks as such:

```
# ip route list
45.32.6.0/23 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 45.32.6.197 
104.238.132.0/23 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 104.238.133.199 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link 
default via 104.238.132.1 dev eth0  src 45.32.6.197
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think [this](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html) could help you.